# Trouble: Pushing Rails App from Cloud 9 to Heroku

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, mobile, heroku, cloud9-ide

I cannot figure it out, I have been searching everywhere, and trying all kinds of methods, but nothing is working. I am at wits end. If anyone could help I would be so grateful.

Link to git: https://github.com/AceConcept/Todo-App

Comment: Post code here, not behind a link.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727047/how-to-use-rails-composer-and-postgresql-on-cloud9-and-deploy-on-heroku) it should be really useful